# Connection problem with KDE Connect

Tags: kubuntu, kde-connect

I am using kubuntu 20.04. KDE Connect was working flawlessly until kubuntu 19.10 kde plasma version 5.18.2. Since the update to plasma 5.18.3 (around February or so), 
 kde connect was not detecting phone and phone couldn't detect desktop.
   I also have Ubuntu installed on the same system. KDE connect installed in ubuntu 19.10 and ubuntu 20.04(upgraded) has no problem detecting.
   I tried even in live usb (kubuntu 20.04), it is not detecting. I also tried with different versions (older) of mobile app. Any light on this issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I make it worked when i added those 3 group of firewall rules (ufw+firewalld+iptables):

```
sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/udp
sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/tcp
sudo ufw reload

sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=1714-1764/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=1714-1764/udp
sudo systemctl restart firewalld.service

sudo iptables -I INPUT -i <yourinterface> -p udp --dport 1714:1764 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -i <yourinterface> -p tcp --dport 1714:1764 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o <yourinterface> -p udp --sport 1714:1764 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o <yourinterface> -p tcp --sport 1714:1764 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect#I_have_two_devices_running_KDE_Connect_on_the_same_network.2C_but_they_can.27t_see_each_other

and most important after that: REBOOT.

I hope it will help you

Comment: for iptables rules find your network interface with: nmcli device status and put the name of the interface connected instead of "<yourinterface>"