# KDE CONNECT issue on KUBUNTU 20.04

Tags: networking, kubuntu, kde, 20.04

After upgrade to Kubuntu Focal Fossa, this app doesn't find my phone.

My topic is also related to these:
[Connection problem with KDE Connect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238487/connection-problem-with-kde-connect)

[KDE Connect - Main phone and Desktop cant see each other - Second phone can see both my Main phone and Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239457/kde-connect-main-phone-and-desktop-cant-see-each-other-second-phone-can-see)

https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=165640&hilit=kde+connect

The conclusion is, that KDE CONNECT works on:

Ubuntu 19.10/20.04 - no problem

Kubuntu 19.10 - no problem

KDE neon 5.18.5 - no problem

Kubuntu 20.04 - not seen some phones

Any ideas where could be the problem, because the app seems OK, but the bug is in Kubuntu? Anything to try?

Comment: Is `firewalld` or `ufw` blocking it? I had to [whitelist the port](https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is not the issue. I have installed gufw before and now with opened ports. So with or w/o firewall, it's the same.

Comment: I'm having the same with a laptop upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 Ubuntu, and a tablet running Android 5. Maybe the old Android is an issue? Works no problem on my phone, Android 10.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the PPA 'backports' installed. In fresh install (focal without backports), this problem didn't arise.